# VS2010 - About the Resource Relative Path - Where are variables declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build a cpp project. On the project resources section there is a resource whose relative path is something like

```
$(QPID_BUILD_ROOT)\src\windows\resources\org.apache.qpid.messaging.rc
```

Where am I suppose to define this variable ? I mean where does VS2010 read this variables value from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are **environment variables**. You can set them for user only, or for the whole system. You also can set what you want "ad-hoc", for example (assuming that your Visual Studio is installed in *c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10* and that you want **x86 build environment**):

1. Go to `start`
2. Type `cmd.exe`
3. At the command prompt:

   "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
4. `set QPID_BUILD_ROOT=[some path]`
5. Launch Visual Studio IDE: `devenv`
   In the Visual Studio IDE you can use a dropdown list (e.g. on one of the VC++ directories) and the click ***Edit***. In the dialog window click ***Macros*** - this will show you all the variables (including the one set above) currently available to Visual Studio.

Of course you don't have to set entire build environment (as shown in **3**), this step is only needed to be able to just type **devenv** instead of typing the whole path to **devenv.exe** in **5**.

Im assuming that you know how to set environment variables for user or the whole system and that you know that you need (at least) to lauch any application again (or even login/logout or reboot) in order for that application to inherit those new variables.

Comment: I set the variable up in windows system environment variable ? Will that work ?

Comment: Yes, it will, but you have to reboot then (sometimes logout/login works).